# Laravel vuex maps

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am trying use vuex map state in laravel, but I get an error.

```
<script>
import mapState from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: mapState({
        progress: state => state.app.loading.progress,
        isActive: state => state.app.loading.active,
        duration: state => state.app.loading.duration,
        height: state => state.app.loading.height,
        canSuccess: state => state.app.loading.canSuccess,
        color: state => state.app.loading.color,
        failedColor: state => state.app.loading.failedColor,
    }),
}
```

[image: Here error screenshot]

Comment: Images of text are not searchable, or accessible, and in general it is better to include the text of the error message and format it using either the code formatting or quotation formatting as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapState` is not the default export of `'vuex'`.
Try this:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
```